# Ping doesn't work when using QEMU user mode networking

Tags: linux, networking, qemu, icmp

I try to use network in guest system. I installed an OS in a virtual machine, but I did not get the network configured. When I try to ping, for instance google.com I get the IP address for the domain, but packets are not transmitted. I tried several guest OS's, but behavior is the same for them, so I suspect that something is wrong with either the qemu itself or with host OS.

I tried both kvm and qemu-system-i386 to run the guest system. Nothing changed.

Pinging from the host system works. Like other network facilities.

Here are some parameters of my host system:

```
$ kvm -version
QEMU emulator version 2.0.0 (Debian 2.0.0+dfsg-6+b1), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
$ uname -a
Linux debian 3.14-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.14.12-1 (2014-07-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How pinging looks like:

```
$ ping google.com
PING google.com (173.194.69.100): 56 data bytes
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
44 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

Additionally, I noticed that port forwarding works. I can connect to the guest via ssh, if I start it as follows:

```
kvm -m 512 -net nic,model=rtl8139 -net user,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22 -drive cache=writeback,index=0,media=disk,file=hd0.img &
```

Answer (score 9):

If you using User-mode-networking in qemu any ICMP protocols (such as ping) [will not work](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/QEMU#User-mode_networking).

Verify whether you are connected to the internet with:

```
curl www.google.com
```

or equivalent.

Comment: Here I describe how to get `ping` working: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473448/how-to-ping-from-the-qemu-guest-to-an-external-url

Answer (score 0):

qemu-system-arm.exe -M versatilepb -cpu arm1176 -hda 2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian.img -kernel kernel-qemu -m 192 -append "root=/dev/sda2" -redir tcp:2222::22

i use the redir flag for internet acces on my Raspbian emulation with Qemu, have you tried it?

Comment: You probably misunderstood my question. Port redirection **works**, I can login to the guest system through ssh. But I **can't** use internet from the guest system.